# Regex for a URL with illegal characters \\

Tags: c#, regex

From the following string:

```
google.com/local/reviews?placeid\\u003dChIJ070npYRaeEgRZNoxwuYYrew\\u0026q\\u003d
```

To extract `u003dChIJ070npYRaeEgRZNoxwuYYrew` although this value will change every time.

I have tried

```
   Regex r = new Regex(@"("(?<=\placeid\\\s+)\p{L}+");
```

Which does not work.

I am guilty of neglecting my knowledge is regex so I apologise if this is painfully easy.

Comment: Is that text a string literal, or plain text?

Comment: It's part of the source code I'll be using regex on.

Comment: It won't work because of `\p` and `\p{L}`, you just need  `var res = Regex.Match(text, @"placeid\\u003d(.*?)(?=\\u0026q|$)")?.Groups[1].Value`. But probably you need to use `Regex.Unescape(text)` , not just `text`, and then ``var res = Regex.Match(Regex.Unescape(text), @"[?&]placeid=([^&]*)")?.Groups[1].Value`` would do. Or, the backslashes may need doubling in the above code. Note that `\u003d` is `=` and `\u0026` is `&`. If you provided a test case snippet it would make answering your question quicker and with more confidence.

Answer (score 1):

There are no whitespace chars in the string that you want to match with `\s+` and there are 2 backslashes.

Using `\p{L}+` only matches any letter and the string that you want also contains numbers.

```
(?<=placeid\\\\\s*)[\p{L}\p{N}]+
```

[Regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3dplaceid%5c%5c%5c%5c%5cs*%29%5b%5cp%7bL%7d%5cp%7bN%7d%5d%2b&i=google.com%2flocal%2freviews%3fplaceid%5c%5cu003dChIJ070npYRaeEgRZNoxwuYYrew%5c%5cu0026q%5c%5cu003d%0d%0a)

For example

```
string pattern = @"(?<=placeid\\\\\s*)[\p{L}\p{N}]+";
string input = @"google.com/local/reviews?placeid\\u003dChIJ070npYRaeEgRZNoxwuYYrew\\u0026q\\u003d";

Match m = Regex.Match(input, pattern);
Console.WriteLine(m.Value);
```

Output

```
u003dChIJ070npYRaeEgRZNoxwuYYrew
```